# Which is the right test?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, categorical-data

I try to find out whether there are significant differences in several Categories between 3 groups groups. If there are differences, in which Category and between which group they occur? My data looks like:

```
Cat  Gr1    Gr2    Gr3
A    125    13      0  
B    10     0       0  
C    87     15      4
D    178    10      1
E    6      0       0                       
F    16     2       0
G    3      23      0
H    261    63      0
```

The numbers are absolute frequencies and i use the R-Software.

My question: Which tests are the correct one and what about a p-value correction because of the multi comparison problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This goes beyond one test, a (Poisson) generalized linear model looks suitable.

Comment: Chi-squared contingency test doesn't work because Gp3 has so little data.

Comment: Thank you for your answers!What do you think about the fishers exact test? Is it possible for tables larger than 2x2?